# Approaching MySql server from NodeJS and Java servers

Tags: java, mysql, node.js

I have a Java server which uses sockets to send\receive data from\to its clients.
I also have a Nodejs server which runs on the same computer and presents the data the users sent on the web.

Ok, both servers run on the same PC and uses the same file system and db which also runs on that same pc. Now I noticed a problem, in which if the Nodejs server insert new row to a certain table, the java server will only see the new row only after it updates another a table.

The row is indeed inserted because I can see it using the PhpMyAdmin in Xamp, so PhpMyAdmin sees it, Nodejs sees it, but not Java. the Java server can query the table multiple times but it won't see the new row until it will update a table.

I'm using Hibernate in my java server:

```
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="native_server/Hibernate_files/t1.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="native_server/Hibernate_files/t2.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="native_server/Hibernate_files/t3.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="native_server/Hibernate_files/t4.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="native_server/Hibernate_files/t5.xml"/>
   <!-- <mapping resource="native_server/t6.xml"/>   -->
 </session-factory>
```

And in my node:

```
 MySql_Connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'username',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'dbname'
 });
```

What can I do so the Java server will see changes made by the Node without periodicly updating the db?

Xamp 1.8.2,

My SQL - 5.5.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Node 0.12.7 & node-mysqk 0.4.2

Comment: Your java server may not be aware that other applications can also update the same database and do not check for updated data regularly. Sinceyou have not shared any details about this java server, I can only guess.

Comment: The Java application won't just magically update the data without querying the database again.